# UDP Server Application program

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to fix this, but I'm having a problem with this line in particular
 throw new System.ArgumentException("Syntax: timeclnt ServerName PortNumber 1");  .....any clue what the heck to do? The server application will need to be provided a port number on which to listen, but how?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class TimeClient
{
    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 2 || args.Length > 2)
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Syntax: timeclnt ServerName PortNumber 1");

        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNum = Int32.Parse(args[1]);

        try
        {
            // Define a string to send to the server
            string stringData = "From the timeClient";

            // Encode it properly
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData);

            // Define a UDP client connection
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

            // Send some data to the server
            client.Send(data, data.Length, hostName, portNum);

            //where to listen for a UDP response
            IPEndPoint recvpt = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            // get the data back from the server
            byte[] receivedData = client.Receive(ref recvpt);

            // output the data received
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedData));

            // all done
            client.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // display an error
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.) Why not args.Length != 2 ? 2.) The exception says 3 arguments: ServerName PortName 1 <-- That means it is always != 2 3.) If the user switches arguments Servername and Port you will get another exception because the string servername cannot be cast to integer.

Comment: @Alina B. I'm not sure how to fix it? I tried putting that in but it said identifier expected. I'm not great with c#

Comment: Cliff, why have you edited your question in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from your `if` condition, you are not passing exactly 2 parameters. If you want 3 parameters, change your condition to

```
 if (args.Length < 3 || args.Length > 3)
```

Comment: I tried changing to that but it didn't make a difference. What port number should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment:

> System.ArgumentException("Syntax: timeclnt ServerName PortNumber 1");

That means there will be passed 3 arguments to your code: ServerName, PortNumber and 1

With 3 arguments passed to your method you have to change your if statement to:

```
if (args.Length != 3)
```